# UDP Proxy for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, windows, proxy, udp

Is there a package for creating a UDP Redirect / Proxy equivalent to that of the HTTP Proxy package 'http-proxy'. I need something that is equally as easy to setup that allows me to enter ports. I'm familiar with NodeJS, so feel free to send anything my way.

Asking for a friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is the [udp-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/udp-proxy), which seems to be a little more effort than http-proxy.